# How to query the amount of global memory?

Tags: cuda

I have used the code in this [link](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~xyuan/cda5125/examples/lect24/devicequery.cu) to query the amount of global memory available in my device but the return value is ZERO.

is it possible that there is no global memory (DRAM) on the device?

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDaIs.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible that there is no global memory (DRAM) on the device?

no, not in your case.   The 840m has a non-zero amount of global memory, for sure.

The code you linked to is broken because it uses an incorrect format specifier for the global memory variable (`%u`) when it should be a format specifier for a 64-bit variable (e.g. `%lu`) here:

```
printf("Total global memory:           %u\n",  devProp.totalGlobalMem);
                                       ^^
```

> How to query the amount of global memory?

You might be better off running the `deviceQuery` CUDA [sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query) , instead.